# Replace all upper case characters with 'X' and all lower case characters with 'x' whilst keeping any spaces or symbols the same

Tags: python, anonymize

I am trying to create a code where I substitute an input string into an 'anonymous' code. I would like to replace all upper case characters with 'X' and all lower case characters with 'x' whilst keeping any spaces or symbols the same.

I understand **<< variable >>.replace<< old value, new value >>** and **if** and **for** loops, but am having trouble implementing them to do what I want, please help?

Sorry if the code I posted isn't proper, I'm new to this

```
input_string   =  input( "Enter a string (e.g. your name): " ) 
lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

for input in input_string:
    if input in input_string:
        input_string = lower.replace(input, "x")

    if input in upper:
        input_string = upper.replace(input, "X")`

print( "The anonymous version of the string is:", input_string )
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain what specifically the problem is.

Comment: Look into using `re.sub` function

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include formatted code

Comment: tried, is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are standard functions to indicate a character is [uppercase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) or [lowercase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower). These are Unicode aware (in Python 3 and newer) so they also work with accented characters. So you can use

```
''.join('x' if x.islower() else 'X' if x.isupper() else x for x in text)
```

where `text` is your input string. For example,

```
input_string   =  input( "Enter a string (e.g. your name): " ) 
result = ''.join('x' if x.islower() else 'X' if x.isupper() else x for x in input_string)
```

with the input

```
I am trying to create a code where I substitute an input string into an 'anonymous' code.
```

results in

```
"X xx xxxxxx xx xxxxxx x xxxx xxxxx X xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxx xx 'xxxxxxxxx' xxxx."
```

Comment: THANK YOU GOOD SIR I LOVE YOU

Answer (score 1):

Strings in python are immutable, so you'll need to build a new one by looping over the input.

In your code, `lower.replace(input, "x")` isn't doing that - that says to replace the contents of the alphabet, whose characters match your input, with an x. In other words, you wanted to do `input.replace` instead, but obviously not try to insert the entire alphabet.

---

Here's an example that checks the case of the characters without typing out the alphabet

```
input_string = input( "Enter a string (e.g. your name): " ) 
output_string = []

for c in input_string: 
    if c.isupper(): 
        output_string.append('X')
    elif c.islower(): 
        output_string.append('x')
    else:
        output_string.append(c) 
print( "The anonymous version of the string is:", ''.join(output_string))
```

Another solution would be to use `re.sub` and `"[A-Z]", "X"`, for example, but that's up to you to learn how those work